# Bouncycastle cannot load when I redeploy application

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I follow this instruction to add bouncycastle:
http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation
but I have still one problem. Sometimes when I redeploy my application this provider isnt found so then my application throw exception. This problem occurs just one per 100 redeploy (maybe less). When I restart my server - weblogic then it start working again. I will be very grateful for any advice why this problem occurs

EDIT:

I am using both method in link above because when I use just one of them then it doesnt work
I add to java.security this provder and then in my class I registered this provder:

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

Comment: The link you provided gives two methods, which are you using?

Comment: both of them I add to java.security this provider and then in my class I registered this provder:     static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

Comment: Can you try only using the static method?

Comment: yes I try this first and it work just with JUnit test. But when I deploy this application to weblogic then it stops working and then I found link above and follow it instruction

Comment: A few thoughts: check the return value from addProvider(), call getProviders() to see if it's there, if you can, set a breakpoint at removeProvider().

Comment: Which algorith are you using of BouncyCastel ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You probably got a `NoClassDefFoundError`. This is a known issue with JSSE implementations.

Here is the scenario:

- Your container loads bouncy castle classes in an application specific ClassLoader
- The provider instance you create depends on that classes and so on that ClassLoader
- Then the provider is registered into JRE API thanks to static fields in top level JVM ClassLoader
- When redeploying, the container discards the application ClassLoader to create a new one
- As the algorithm is already known, the second provider insertion fails silently
- When using the algorithm the provider instance is simply unusable because the ClassLoader has been discarded
- Then the only option is to restart the container to get the situation fixed.

As there is no standard listener for the undeploy event, it is not possible to trigger the JSSE provider removal at time.

The recommended way to avoid that trouble is to have bouncy castle classes in your JVM ClassPath or in your container ClassPath. You have to remove it from your application. Now you need to register BC provider with an alternate option to the static initializer. WebLogic provides [ways to trigger code at server startup](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13728/notifications.htm#JMXCU222) (I have used server startup class), this code will be responsible to register JSSE providers for the whole server/JVM lifetime.

An alternate option is to add the following line in JRE `java.security` file with bouncy castle jar in `jre/lib/ext` but I do not like that way because it may be lost when updating: `security.provider.7=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`

So then the application simply expects implementations are there, it may be a good idea to add tests for algorithm availability to report any troubles to operators and users.

Comment: I've run into the exact same issue and Yves' answer is exactly what resolved it.

Comment: hm very nice answer. I will try it but it is really hard to test this because this problems occurs just few time in hunderts of redeploying. Do you know why this problems occurs just sometimes ? But I trust to A. R. Younce and set this answer as right. thx a lot

Comment: When I got first the trouble it was years ago and it fails at every redeploy. Probably WebLogic has been improved to be able to work-around the issue. It mainly depends if BC has been effectively used or not, or if all required classes has been loaded/instantiated at least once or some are lacking after redeploy like here https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2139251

Comment: Thanks, copied lib in jre/lib/ext and added security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider in jre/lib/security/java.security.

Answer (score 10):

I use this work around for redeploy the application in Tomcat :

```
public class GenSignCastle {
    BouncyCastleProvider        bcProvider = null;

public GenSignCastle() {
    if ( bcProvider == null ) {
        bcProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();

        String name = bcProvider.getName();
        Security.removeProvider( name ); // remove old instance

        Security.addProvider( bcProvider );
    }
}
.
.
.
}
```

The interesting thing is I have to remove the BouncyCastleProvider first to use it again after redeploy.

Comment: Removing the BC provider during the shutdown process of the web application worked perfectly!

Comment: When removing the provider during shutdown the provider name can be retrieved from `BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

this issue could easily be solved by the following code and usage of the sun.security.jce package:

```
ProviderList list = Providers.getFullProviderList();
ProviderList.add(list, new BouncyCastleProvider());
Providers.beginThreadProviderList(list);
```

the list will be extended to use the bouncy castle provider and the new list will be injected as a thread local. this could be used inside a servletfilter or something else. maybe it is necessary to reset the list to the old value after the request is finished

```
Providers.endThreadProviderList(this.oldList);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (I get a `No installed provider supports this key:`), as far as I can understand from JavaDoc it's only usable internally by JAR verifier, not with general usage of JCE providers.