# OpenSAML / Spring security setup so redeploy on Tomcat works

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security, spring-saml, opensaml

We're running a webapp on OpenJDK IcedTea6 1.13.6 using Tomcat 6.0.35. For SSO we're using the Spring security SAML extension, which bases on OpenSAML 2.6.1.

When re-deploying our application (without restarting Tomcat), I get a 
    NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/paddings/ISO10126d2Padding
which is very nicely described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379799/bouncycastle-cannot-load-when-i-redeploy-application). From an Eclipse MAT analysis, I gather that either BouncyCastleProvider or JCERSAPublicKey are preventing the WebappClassLoaderfrom being gc'ed.

How do I configure SAML so that all (bouncy castle) instances are properly destroyed? I have a hard time believing that SAML is designed such that a deployment mandates a Tomcat restart.

My current configuration:
    ...

```
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger">
    <property name="logErrors" value="true"/>
    <property name="logMessages" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="mypassword"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="tenzingfaces" value="keyphrase"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="tenzingfaces"/>
</bean>

<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

<bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetails" ref="samlUserDetailService" />
    <property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="samlUserDetailService" class="ch.umbrella.springframework.security.SamlUserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

<bean id="samlSuccessRedirectHandler" class="ch.umbrella.springframework.security.SsoAuthenticationSuccessHandler" >
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/main.html" />
    <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false" />
    <property name="credentialsExpiredUrl" value="/credentialsexpired.html" />
</bean>
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="samlSuccessRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <ref bean="postBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>
<bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>
<bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>
<bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

<bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" scope="singleton" init-method="initialize"/>
<bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder" scope="singleton"/>
...
```

And, in a staging-specific file:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate" destroy-method="destroy">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider" destroy-method="destroy">
                        <constructor-arg ref="timer1" />
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/security/idp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate" destroy-method="destroy">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider" destroy-method="destroy">
                        <constructor-arg ref="timer2" />
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/security/localhost_sp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="local" value="true"/>
                        <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                        <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="tenzingfaces"/>
                        <property name="encryptionKey" value="tenzingfaces"/>
                        <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false" />
                        <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false" />
                        <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false" />
                        <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="hostedSPName" value="https://hurricane.umbrellanet.ch/uf-test/saml/metadata" />
</bean>
```

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are bundling the bouncycastle jars in your war, then don't do that. Instead put those jars in tomcat/lib . Hopefully, that would fix it.