# java NoClassDefFoundError but Class is there and Usable

Tags: java, liferay, classloader, liferay-6, noclassdeffounderror

i have a very strange(for me) Question. I use bouncy castle to de-/crypt some Mails in a Web Application. I get this Exception after redeployment of my Application

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/spec/SkeinParameterSpec
>           at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseMac.engineInit(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.crypto.Mac.init(Mac.java:443)
>           at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.calculatePbeMac(Unknown Source)
>           at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
>           at *my.application.Class*.getDecryptedContent(*my.application.Class*.java:401)
>           at *my.application.Class*.decrypt(*my.application.Class*.java:91)
>           at *my.application.Class*.getKvConnectMail(*my.application.Class*.java:320)
>           at *my.application.Class*.processEinClick(*my.application.Class*.java:198)
>           at *my.application.Class*.shedule(*my.application.Class*.java:44)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
>           at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
>           at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
>           at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

So i thought the lib is missing in WEB-INF/lib folder of my Application but it is there.

The strange thing is: If i use the Class direct with this Codesnipped the Snipped is executed correct without errors.

```
LOGGER.error("Class!!!: " + SkeinParameterSpec.class.getName());
SkeinParameterSpec spec = new SkeinParameterSpec();
LOGGER.error("Instance!!!: " + spec.toString());
LOGGER.error("Instanceof: " + (spec instanceof SkeinParameterSpec));
```

But the Library Class org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseMac which uses near the same code as my snipped ends with the Exception above.

Somebody out there who can help me to understand why this happens?

P.S.:
This only happens after a redeployment if restart the whole Tomcat every thinks works.

**UPDATE 1:**
I have forgotten to say that i use Liferay. But my WebApplication is a normal one without any relations to Liferay.

But: After some investigation i found out that Liferay have some librarys (/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/lib). Also Bouncycastle in an old version. Is it possible that this librarys are used by my WebApplication and the error is a result of Liferay's librarys and CustomClassLoaders?

**Solution:**
See 'inigo skimmer' comment at the right answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess there may be  another version of bouncycastle lib on the classpath (may be in Tomcat/lib folder) or required by some other jar that is loaded first and doesn't contain the desired class.

Comment: Good tip but no. My Application is the only one who use it. And in tomcat libs is no bouncycastle lib.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379799/bouncycastle-cannot-load-when-i-redeploy-application)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that BouncyCastle registers with the current ClassLoader and that is unloaded when you restart the web app. You should register BouncyCastle in the JRE itself. See [NoClassDefFoundError on BouncyCastle class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881126/noclassdeffounderror-on-bouncycastle-class)